# How to make a download button for files taken from a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to print out all the files that I've saved in a database and then make it possible to download them. I am able to echo them, but I don't know how to make a download "button" to download them to the computer.
The datbase has two columns: ID and Ime.

I tried using a tag from HTML with no luck. I was able to echo buttons next to file names, but I couldn't download them (I tried using file_put_contents method)

This is the code that outputs file names (Ime = Name in my language).

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','usbw','down');
$query = "SELECT * FROM datoteka";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($result_check > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row["Ime"]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

The output looks like this:

```
datoteka2019-04-01-15-44.doc
datoteka2019-04-01-15-48.doc
datoteka2019-04-01-15-16.pdf
```

Files in database that I want to be able to download (3 for now, could be more)
[image: database picture]

There should be a download button (or something cliclkable) next to each file name on website that would enable me to download this file from the database (one file at time, not all at once).

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a third column with the file data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once made a similar script, what you have to do is set some headers and echo the data from database.

An example of that could be, assuming that the data is in `$row['filedata']`, the following

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['Ime']);
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $row['filedata'];
?>
```

Now you have to know what file to download first, and for that we can use a GET or POST parameter

```
<?php
$fileID = htmlentities($_GET['fileID']);
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','usbw','down');
$fileID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fileID); // ALWAYS ESCAPE USER INPUT
$query = "SELECT * FROM datoteka where `ID`=$fileID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($result_check > 1 || $result_check < 1){ //If more then 1 result die
    die('inavlid ID');
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
//and here the above mentioned lines
?>
```

The easiest way to add a download button to the page would be by using the window.open() function in JavaScript like so:

```
echo $row['Ime']."<button onclick='window.open(\"download.php?fileID=".$row['ID']."\");'>Download</button><br>";
```

This will open a new window which will download the file

The total would look something like this
For download.php:

```
<?php
$fileID = htmlentities($_GET['fileID']);
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','usbw','down');
$fileID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fileID); // ALWAYS ESCAPE USER INPUT
$query = "SELECT * FROM datoteka where `ID`=$fileID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($result_check > 1 || $result_check < 1){ //If more then 1 result die
    die('inavlid ID');
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['Ime']);
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $row['filedata'];
?>
```

and for index.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','usbw','down');
$query = "SELECT * FROM datoteka";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$result_check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($result_check > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['Ime']."<button onclick='window.open(\"download.php?fileID=".$row['ID']."\");'>Download</button><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this code isn't working for me completely. I fixed a syntax mistake on line 6 in download.php (space between $ and query) and I think there is a mistake on line 14 in download.php as well, but I'm not sure. What I get for output after trying to download a file is this:

Comment: 1 || $result_check < 1){ //If more then 1 result die die('inavlid ID'); } $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); header("Cache-Control: public"); header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['Ime']); header("Content-Type: application/zip"); header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); echo $row['filedata']; ?>

Comment: Oh yes you are right, the $row['Ime'] is still in the quotes, I'm patching it up. And the other error is because I typed `<?` instead of `<?php`

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark a question as answered so future users can find it too

Answer (score -1):

You can read here https://www.php.net/file_put_contents,
and you need to know where the path file is. ex:

> /users/john/downloads/namefile.doc

Comment: `file_put_contents();` is a way to _write_ to files, but he wants to download them, from a database so I don't think this is exactly what he was looking for.